# Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list (Component)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, software-installation, terminal

I am trying to install software in my raspberry pi running resbian. Every time I try to install anything from through the terminal I get "Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list (Component) The list of sources could not be read."

EDIT: After tying "sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list" I get "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/  main" is response, my friend was using the device and may have attempted an install of the "Brave Browser", how do I remove the file? When I open a file explorer and dig down to the file I can't remove it due to insufficient privileges.

Comment: What's in the file? It's not a standard Raspbian file. You probably tried to install a program ('brave browser'?) and that created a file with the above problem. If you're not sure about the contents then you should add it to the question so that others can help you. Deleting the file would also solve the problem...

Comment: please add to the question the output of the following command: `sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list`

Comment: @Dirk That may be possible, my friend was using my pi for a bit so he might have done something, how do I delete it?

Comment: @JaromandaX I get "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/  main", I will also edit my response to include this information.

Comment: You can remove the file with the `rm` (remove) command. Use `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to delete the unneeded and malformed file "*/etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list*". On the command line just execute this command:

```
rpi ~$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list
```

Comment: note: the command starts is just `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-.list` ... the first bit, `rpi ~$` is the command prompt

Answer (score -1):

Simple removal.

`sudo apt rm /brave-release-.list`

Comment: If I try the command, I get `E: Invalid operation rm`. **apt** does not have an operation `rm`. Where is your typo?